# Rxjs, fromEvent to handle multiple events

Tags: angular, rxjs5, rxjs-dom

What is the best way to handle multiple events on the same DOM node in rxjs 5.1?

`fromEvent($element, 'event_name')` but I can specify only one event at a time.

I want handle `scroll wheel touchmove touchend` events.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

*Note: This is for RxJS v5. See bottom of this answer for the v6 and v7 equivalent.*

---

You can use the [`Rx.Observable.merge`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js%7EObservable.html#static-method-merge) function to merge multiple observable streams into a single stream:

```javascript
// First, create a separate observable for each event:
const scrollEvents$    = Observable.fromEvent($element, 'scroll');
const wheelEvents$     = Observable.fromEvent($element, 'wheel');
const touchMoveEvents$ = Observable.fromEvent($element, 'touchmove');
const touchEndEvents$  = Observable.fromEvent($element, 'touchend');

// Then, merge all observables into one single stream:
const allEvents$ = Observable.merge(
    scrollEvents$,
    wheelEvents$,
    touchMoveEvents$,
    touchEndEvents$
);
```

If that seems a little bloated, we might clean up a little by creating an array for the events, and then map that array to Observable objects. This works best *if* you do not need to reference the events their associated observables separately at some point:

```javascript
const events = [
    'scroll',
    'wheel',
    'touchmove',
    'touchend',
];

const eventStreams = events.map((ev) => Observable.fromEvent($element, ev));
const allEvents$ = Observable.merge(...eventStreams);
```

You are now able to handle all events with one single subscription:

```javascript
const subscription = allEvents$.subscribe((event) => {
    // do something with event...
    // event may be of any type present in the events array.
});
```

---

**Update for RxJS v6 and v7**

Starting from RxJS 6 you can import the standalone [`merge`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/merge) and [`fromEvent`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/fromEvent) functions equivalent to the static methods in v5, and use them the same way:

```javascript
import { fromEvent, merge } from 'rxjs';

const scrollEvents = fromEvent($element, 'scroll');
// creating other input observables...

const allEvents$ = merge(
    scrollEvents$,
    wheelEvents$,
    touchMoveEvents$,
    touchEndEvents$
);
```

Comment: Could you please help me with, If we want to trigger scroll event only if wheel event is triggered?

Answer (score 6):

This is how I would implement this in the newest version of RxJs

```
const events = ['scroll', 'resize', 'orientationchange']
from(events)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(event => fromEvent($element, event))
  )
  .subscribe(
    event => // Do something with the event here
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I prefer to combine events:

```
fromEvents(dom, "scroll", "wheel", "touch", "etc...");
function fromEvents(dom, ...eventNames: string[]) {
    return eventNames.reduce(
        (prev, name) => Rx.merge(prev, fromEvent(dom, name)),
        Rx.empty()
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, Below hopefully is easier to read.

```js
        import {fromEvent, merge} from "rxjs";
        
        
        const mousemoveEvent = fromEvent(document, 'mousemove');
        const wheelEvent = fromEvent(document, 'wheel');
        const leftclickEvent = fromEvent(document, 'auxclick');
        const rightclickEvent = fromEvent(document, 'click');
        const keyboardEvent = fromEvent(document, 'keydown');

        const allEvents = merge(
            mousemoveEvent, wheelEvent, leftclickEvent, rightclickEvent, keyboardEvent
        )
```